# How to reuse a retrain model

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm following the tutorial of [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) using a pre-trained VGG16 network.

I was able to get a decent accuracy of the dataset :) However, how can I **reuse the re-trained network**?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_class, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
      loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
      epochs=epochs,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))

# After training, I save my model
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(top_model_json_path, "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
```

And I would like to reuse it with [previous trained top layer classifier](https://github.com/Weijay/Tranfer-Learning-using-Keras/blob/master/retrain.ipynb), given an image like `dog.1234.jpg`

```
def main(_):
  # vgg16 
  vgg_model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

  # load top model and weights
  json_file = open('retrain_VGG16_dogcat2000.json', 'r')
  loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
  json_file.close()

  top_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
  top_model.load_weights("retrain_VGG16_dogcat2000.h5")

  # concatenate vgg16 and top classifier 
  model = Model(inputs=vgg_model.input, outputs=top_model(vgg_model.output)) # error occurs

  # test
  image = cv2.imread(FLAGS.img_dir)
  image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224)).astype(np.float32) / 255.
  image = image.reshape(1 , image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
  model.predict(image)
```

Error occurs: `The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 512). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VGG model does not have a well defined input shape. It's accepting images of any size. Since it's a purely convolutional model, the output shape will also be variable. That's why the shapes show as `(None, None, 512)`.

But a `Flatten` layer (which is present in your own `top_model`) does not support a variable input shape. It must use a well defined one.

You have then two possible solutions:

- For fixed image sizes: define the input shape of the VGG model with `input_shape=(224,224,3)` (this will not require that you retrain this model, the weights do not depend on the size of the image in a purely convolutional model)
- For variable image sizes: add a global pooling layer at the beginning of your top model to eliminate the spatial variable dimensions. Use the `GlobalAveragePooling2D`. (This may reduce the capability of your model though, and it will certainly require retraining everything)

Comment: how can I define the input shape of the VGG model?  BTW, I can use my retrained model as mentioned in another answer, but i'm not sure whether it is right the pipeline to do so.

Comment: `vgg_model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224,224,3))`

Comment: About it being the right to do, that depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently able to reuse my retrained model this way. But how can I concatenate my retrained model into one machine learning model?

```
classes = ['cat', 'dog']
# load VGG model
vgg_model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

# load model and weights
json_file = open('retrain_VGG16_dogcat2000.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
top_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
top_model.load_weights("retrain_VGG16_dogcat2000.h5")

# test image
image = cv2.imread(FLAGS.img_dir)
image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224)).astype(np.float32) / 255.
image = image.reshape(1 , image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])

# predict the image throughout vgg net
vgg_out = vgg_model.predict(image)

# predict the top_model with input from vgg's output
prediction = top_model.predict(vgg_out)

print(prediction, classes[np.argmax(prediction)])
```

> `python evaluate.py --img_dir ~/datasets/dog_cat/dog.4457.jpg`
>
> [[5.281641e-32 1.000000e+00]] dog
>
> `python evaluate.py --img_dir ~/datasets/dog_cat/cat.2345.jpg`
>
> [[1.000000e+00 9.587834e-36]] cat